# Code Runner extension Run Very Slow in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

So i recently just bought a new gaming laptop, it's an Asus Tuf, but strangely when i install vs code in my new laptop and code some algorithm with c++ andd using Code Runner extension to compile and run my program, it run very slow compared to my old Asus laptop. I just develop a simple CRUD program in the vs code in my new laptop but to run the code, it sometime take average 5-7 seconds using code runner, sometimes even more than 10 or more than 15 seconds, but it take no longer than 5 second (most of the Times it take even no longer than 1 second) to run the code in my older laptop

So I tried to turn on the sync in vs code on both of my laptop using github account to sync the setting from my older laptop to my new laptop, hoping it Will run faster, but it still run very slow

Comment: compiler? compiler version? compile flags?